# mysql query: load the information into the form fields in the CMS

Tags: php, mysql

I've hit a bit of a problem, I'm currently working on a custom CMS that allows the user to change the websites title, description, keywords and footer, as well as various other settings, which are all kept in one mysql table called site_settings which has two columns

setting and content, the setting column holds the settings name, for example title, and the content holds the information such as "welcome to my website", these are loaded into the site by various queries which works great, the trouble im having is I want to load the information into the form fields in the CMS, which I was hoping to do with the following query

```
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT `setting`, `content` FROM `site_settings`");
```

and then create an array with the information using:

```
$content = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

but the only way to get the information is to make a while statement that cycles through every row until it reaches the end, but what i want to be able to do is use the setting column in my table as the main identifier for retrieving the content

for example at the moment with the while array my arrays look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => title [1] => title [2] => title [3] => title )
Array ( [0] => keywords [1] => keywords [2] => keywords [3] => keywords )
Array ( [0] => description [1] => description [2] => description [3] => description )
Array ( [0] => footnote [1] => footnote [2] => footnote [3] => footnote )
Array ( [0] => notice_state [1] => notice_state [2] => 1 [3] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => maintenance_state [1] => maintenance_state [2] => 1 [3] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => notice_message [1] => notice_message [2] => notice [3] => notice )
Array ( [0] => maintenance_message [1] => maintenance_message [2] => maintenance [3] => maintenance )
Array ( [0] => about_us [1] => about_us [2] => about us [3] => about us )
Array ( [0] => article_shorten_length [1] => article_shorten_length [2] => 80 [3] => 80 )
```

so id have to cycle through them all to retrieve all the information, with the following statement:

```
while($content = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo $content['content'];
}
```

but what I'm looking to do is put them all into one array with 1 or a few mysql statements like so

```
Array (

title -> 'welcome to my website',
description -> 'this is my website',
)
```

etc...

and just echo in the information by calling the setting column from my array without using a while statement and without a separate mysql query for each row like:

```
$content['title'];
$content['description'];
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop with [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    $content[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```

This avoids reading the whole result set into an array that you then discard.  It might be more efficient, therefore.

Answer (score 1):

I am really unsure as to what exactly you want. But if I get your question properly, are you looking for the below:

```
while($content=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    $finalResultObj[$content['setting'] ] = $content['content'];
```

After this, you have an associative array, and (if I have understood your question properly) you would be able to use it like `$finalResultObj['setting']` to get the relevant content.

Are you sure, this is what you want?